# How to add dojo-maven dependency?

Tags: maven, dojo

I am currently trying to add dojo as maven dependency in a web project.

I found this link: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.dojotoolkit/dojo-maven/1.8.0
where I copied the dependency node into my POM.

Next I searched where the dojo-maven artefact lies (in which repository). But I cannot find this information. I tried adding:

```
<repository>
<id>maven2repo</id>
<url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

But when I build it sais:    Could not find artifact org.dojotoolkit:dojo-maven:jar:1.8.0 in maven2repo (http://central.maven.org/maven2/)

The dojo-maven artefact can be found here http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22dojo-maven%22

Another place to search can be here http://download.dojotoolkit.org/ under the maven category.

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: same problem... the <dependency> tag has correct info, but it still cannot be found in central Maven repo

Comment: same problem here did u solved it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a dependency defined in your pom?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.dojotoolkit</groupId>
  <artifactId>dojo</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This will only add the "compiled" dojo code.  It is not the full SDK (with the build utilities, etc).  There is an outstanding ticket to publish the full SDK to the maven repository.

http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15120

Comment: I verified that <dependency> is correct, but I am still having the same issue.